# Rebuild indexes on replication server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have 1 live server and 1 replication server, for reporting purpose we use the replication server and in replication server we have created index. So I want to know if I rebuild my index on replication server do I have to remove the replication first and then rebuild the index or can I directly rebuild the indexes on replication server.
Thanks!! in advance

Comment: what type of replication you are having,one way replication or bidirectional replication

Comment: 1 way replication and I am using transactional replication

Comment: Better to ask Database administration related question here http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove replication,i am not sure why you thought of this..

But while rebuilding indexes,you have to rebuild on both Publisher  and subscriber (order not important)..It seems Fragmentation will not be solved,when you rebuild indexes only on publisher

http://sqlfool.com/2009/01/fragmentation-on-replicated-tables/

Comment: But on publisher we don't have that index, we have created index for reporting purpose

Comment: there will be no issues,if you rebuild indexes on any server